# Making sure my Go page view counter isn't abused

Tags: go

I believe I have a found a very good and fast solution for efficiently counting page views:

Working example in go playground here: https://play.golang.org/p/q_mYEYLa1h

My idea is to push this to the database every X minutes, and after pushing a key then delete it from the page map.

My question now is, what would be the optimal way to ensure that this isn't abused? Ideally, I would only want to increase page count from the same person if there was a time interval of 2 hours since last visiting the page.
As far as I know, it would be ideal to store and compare both IP and user agent (I don't want to rely on cookie/localstorage), but I'm not quite sure how to efficiently store and compare this information.

I'd likely get both the IP (`req.Header.Get("x-forwarded-for")`) and UserAgent (`req.UserAgent()`) from http.Request.

I was thinking making a visitor struct similar to my page struct that would look like this:

```
type visitor struct {
    mutex          sync.Mutex
    urlIPUAAndTime map[string]time
}
```

This way should make it possible to do something similar to before. However, imagine if the website had so many requests that there would be hundreds of millions of unique visitor maps being stored, and each of these could only be deleted after 2 (or more) hours. I therefore think this is not a good solution.

I guess it would be ideal/necessary to write to and read from some file, but not sure how this should be done efficiently. Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: most of the optimization may not be required, however at our office, since we are handling lots of data; we use nosql to store various updates from various clients, then we do some sort of analytical with our data continue with some sort of summary with our data; thus we put a little concern on how client update, and more about what the update itself

Comment: Define "the same person".

Comment: @zerkms maybe "same device" is a better term. Should prevent a person from increasing the view counter by simply refreshing the page

Comment: @fisker HTTP does not have a "device" notion. Just set a cookie with the last counted visit time.

Comment: @zerkms But I think comparing both IP and UserAgent will achieve same result. It may not be 100% accurate (and could potentially be abused by Tor users?) but I'd like to think that it would have 99+% accuracy assuming the website target a similar user base as reddit/imgur/twitchtv/youtube/etc

Comment: @fisker you need to remember IP and UserAgent server-side. And the cookie solution is entirely stateless. While provides the same (low) level of protection.

Comment: @zerkms but I think a cookie based solution can easily be abused compared to a server-side IP + UA solution. When I think cookie/localstorage based solution, then I think that if said cookie/localstorage entity doesn't exist, then it must be a new visitor. So what would prevent someone from simply deleting the cookie/localstorage entity and refresh the page? (I assume it's also possible to simply block a website from setting cookie/loclastorage)

Comment: Any of those can easily be abused, I don't see the difference. But the cookie solution is much cheaper and easier to implement/maintain. Now consider whether you want to invest more to a solution that provides effectively the same low level of protection. I'm not insisting, decide yourself.

Comment: How would you abuse a server side solution that relied on `req.Header.Get("x-forwarded-for")` and `req.UserAgent()`? You may say by using Tor (which as far as I remember requires restarting the browser whenever you want a new IP, so very troublesome) but I guess could just ignore all visitors coming from Tor.

Comment: The User-Agent is set by the client, so you cannot trust it. At all. `curl -H user-agent:whatever-I-want ...`. Some browser extensions randomize the User-Agent in an attempt to increase privacy. Btw, the mutex field should be a pointer (*sync.Mutex). Run go vet.

Comment: @Peter I would say with UA solution then can compare the string with all popular browser UA strings (although I admit it might be a pain to always update such a package), but yeah, didn't really consider browser extensions randomizing the UA. Thanks for the `go vet` tip (not sure how I've never heard about that before..), I can never seem to grasp pointers no matter how much I read about it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of optimization ways is to add a Bloom filter before this map. Bloom filter is a probabilistic structure which can say one of these:

- this user is definitely new
- and this user possibly was here

This is a way to cut off computation on early stage. If many of your users are new then you save requests to database to check all of them. 
What if structure says "user is possibly non-unique"? Then you go the database and check it. 
Here's one more optimization: if you do not need very accurate information and can agree with mistake about several percent, you may use the sole bloom filter. I guess many large sites use this technique for estimation.

Comment: Hmm, been reading a bit up on Bloom filters - it sounds quite complex. If I understand correctly, then the bloom filter would be part of the page struct? But the bloom filter needs to be initialized with N amount of items, where each item was a combined IP+UA string. But let's say I want to be very optimistic (to put it mildly) and assume one page may one day obtain 1 billion unique visitors. This means that every single page would have to be initialized with 1 billion items since it's impossible to increase it once it's first set?

Comment: I've been thinking some more, maybe one solution would be to have a bloom filters slice, where the initial item size was 1000, if it got filled up, then could append a new filter with a size of 50.000, then 100.000, etc. Not sure if that makes sense or if it's efficient/inefficient (or even possible)..

Comment: Another option would perhaps be to simply delete and replace the bloomfilter when it reached 1000. That way it would still be possible for the same visitor to account for multiple views (which is not a bad thing), but he wouldn't be able to abuse it since it would require 999 other views before his new view would be counted.

Comment: Bloom filter can be separate structure before the main one. There're several realisations on github thou I haven't look through them. One good feature of BF is its possibility to be tuned in terms of required memory - false positive probability - number of unique keys. Here's a calculator - https://hur.st/bloomfilter?n=1000000000&p=0.01 You need about 1.12GB space for 1B keys with false positive probability of 1%.

Comment: You may have 3 filters keeping values for 3 last hours with shift 1 hour. So every time, you use first filter, but write to all 3. At the beginning of every hour you throw off fest filter and shift them 2->1, 3->2. Also you add one more clean filter for 3rd place.

Comment: You allocate memory for the filter once on creation. Then it doesn't grow.

Comment: Space requirements: 3x1.Gb ~ 4GB. Keeping on disk all keys will take 1B * sizeof (IP + UserAgent). I think this can help save memory.

Comment: Little easier idea: hash (ip+ua) then map take only last 30-bits and put data into 125M memory - just set corresponding bit. I have not tested this. I think this will give more false positive but will work faster and use less space.

Comment: Thanks a lot, especially love the last tip. I think one thing to keep in mind is that each page should have their own bloom filter, so if 1B keys would require 1.12GB space then imagine if 1000 different pages had been visited within the last 2 hours (at least if I understand correctly, then what you propose would only allow one page count for the entire website rather than a single page of the website)

Comment: I do think that for me, the ideal solution would be bloom filters with 1000 keys, and whenever all keys were used up then could reset the bloom filter. This way then it will also be possible for the same user to have multiple page visit counts when returning after 2 hours (or after 1000 other people have visited the page) which I think gives a very good protection against abuse (and there would be no need to store the bloom filter data in a file/database/etc). I'll accept this answer tomorrow if there's no better solution by then

Comment: I think you do not need 1000 maps: one for every page. Just try to add URL to hash - and if user is visiting same page hash won't be unique.